# What does Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115 mean? Where can I adjust this setting?

Tags: php, centos, yum

Error: Package: php55w-5.5.9-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64
Error: Package: php55w-5.5.9-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: httpd

Answer (score 1):

`Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115` means that some package (probably php55w in your case) needs package *httpd-mmn* in version *20051115* installed. If you are just consuming binary (i.e. already built) package, you can not adjust it. It is there because package maintainer believes it is required for that package to work.

I believe that uninstalling *php-common* package would help in your case:

```
yum remove php-common
yum install php55w
```

But I would consider using Software Collections repository (which have PHP 5.5 as well) - packages from there can play with rest of the system nicely.

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/?search=php